# Using an intent to forward users to twitter app with pre-determiend search keyword

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter, hashtag

I want to be able to switch between my app and twitters app to show a search for a pre-determined hashtag.

I have an on click listener & sending the user to the twitter app... loading the tweets and allowing the discussion of that hashtag. There is the logic but how can I do this? What I get now is just my feed and a drop down list of previous searches.

Here is the listener & intent code:

```
final Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.C_Twitter_Button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("twitter://search?f=realtime&q=%23KeyWord"));
            startActivity(intent);

        }catch (Exception e) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/search?f=realtime&q=%23KeyWord")));
        }
    }
});
```

Can anyone offer me a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The search query was wrong :(

The solution is to use the following url to search the twitter app:

**twitter://search?query=%23hashtag**

Cheers